# Yii2 fragment caching give an error not found begin

Tags: yii2, memcached

I am trying to use `FragmentCaching` but some error occurs. Seems like the `view` can't find the `beginCache` tag. What i am trying is :

```
$this->beginCache("filterContent", ['duration' => '86400', 'variations' => [\Yii::$app->language]]);
        //my dataprovider
$this->endCache();
```

And what i get is :

```
Unexpected yii\widgets\FragmentCache::end() call. A matching begin() is not found.
```

Did everything like the documentation of yii2 says.Tried to find some answer around the google but without result.Will appreciate every advice!

Comment: Actually, in the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-fragment.html) it's stated that you should place the cached fragment in the `if` block with `endCache()` inside

Comment: Nothing to say. The most common mistake i am making. Overlooking half of the stuffs.Thank you very much!